# adding fragment using a For loop in different containers

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist

I have a arraylist of size 10, I want to load a fragment based on id, 4 times in four different containers. Everytime I'm sending a different id to my fragment in bundle using loop, and which is correct. 
But the problem is my fragment only gets one id (which is the last ) and shows it on layout.

I want it to work like this way, 
when i= 0: get the id from arraylist, pass it to fragment and load the data       of that id and show in container1 and do the same for all containers.

please check my code where i'm making mistake in loading or replacing fragments

```
   SubFragment frag;
   Bundle bundle;
   RelativeLayout fLayout;
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp;

        for (int i = 0; i<= categoryArrayList.size();i++ ) {
             if (i != 6) {
                 if (i == 0){
                     frag = new SubFragment();
                     fLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
                     bundle = new Bundle();

                     categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId();
                     bundle.putInt("categoryID", (categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
                     bundle.putString("categoryName", categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());
                     lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                     lp.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
                     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                     lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                     fLayout.addView(, lp);

                     frag.setArguments(bundle);
                     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                             .replace(fLayout.addView(fLayout,lp),frag)
                     .commit(); // how to replace a fragment here
             }               
              else if(i==1){

                     frag = new SubFragment();
                     categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId();
                     bundle.putInt("categoryID", (categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
                     bundle.putString("categoryName", categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());
                     Log.v("for loop i",Integer.toString(i));
                     Log.v("for loop id",Integer.toString(categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
                     Log.v("for loop name",categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());

                     frag.setArguments(bundle);
                     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container2, frag).commit();
                 }
                 else if(i==3){

                     frag = new SubFragment();
                     categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId();
                     bundle.putInt("categoryID", (categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
                     bundle.putString("categoryName", categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());
                     Log.v("for loop i",Integer.toString(i));
                     Log.v("for loop id",Integer.toString(categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelCategoryId()));
                     Log.v("for loop name",categoryArrayList.get(i).getChannelName());

                     frag.setArguments(bundle);
                     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container3, frag).commit();
                 }

            }


            else{
                 Log.v("else",Integer.toString(i));

                 break;
             }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Where creating `bundle` Object?, do it before adding value in it for every condition

Comment: Just add `bundle=new Bundle();` before adding data in `bundle`

Comment: Thank you so much. It solved my problem

Comment: Sir how to replace a fragment in programmatically created relative or frame layout. I have updated the code.